# java server throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

Tags: illegalstateexception

please help me
java server throws : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
I rechecked many times and googled alot but i cant find what's the problem
here's my code

```
    DataOutputStream stream = null;
BufferedInputStream buf = null;
try {
response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
response.setHeader(Constants.AU_TRST_X_RESULT_CD, "0"); // x-resultCd = 0 is OK
// add RSP_KEY_CODE to header
response.setHeader(Constants.RSP_KEY_CODE, Constants.RSP_SUCCCESS + "");
response.setContentType("application/csv");
//------------ write csv file to body ----------
// get response's outputStream
stream = new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
// fix file csv
File csvFixFile = new File("E:\\a.xls");   
// buffer to read csv File

File csvResponse = new File(csvFixFile.getPath());
// file Input to read csv File
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(csvResponse);
buf = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
int readBytes = 0;
while ((readBytes = buf.read()) != -1) {
stream.write(readBytes);
}

} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
if (null != buf)
try {buf.close();} catch (Exception e2) {e2.printStackTrace();}
if (null != stream)
try {stream.close();} catch (Exception e2) {e2.printStackTrace();}  
}
```

.It looks okay but it didnt work properly and perhaps the problem is in the while loop
please point it out for me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IOUtils from apache commons-io to copy input stream into output stream (it also uses buffer, so you don't need to):

```
ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outStream);
```

[IOUtils javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html)